# Google map fragment has trouble inflating

Tags: android, google-maps, fragment

I've been adding a map to an Android project of mine and when ever my class loads the XML file with the map fragment it crashes, I was following this tutorial

( https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#the_google_maps_api_key )

I'm using a Nexus 7 (Jellybean 4.1) so that shouldn't be a problem, here is my class:

```
package com.app.thetoolstore;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Tool_map extends Activity{

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map_activity);
    }


}
```

And here is my XML:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#001" >


<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>



</LinearLayout>
```

and finally my Stack Trace:

```
04-04 10:01:35.551: E/AndroidRuntime(14362): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-04 10:01:35.551: E/AndroidRuntime(14362): java.lang.RuntimeException:   Unable to     start activity ComponentInfo{com.app.thetoolstore/com.app.thetoolstore.Tool_map}:  android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29: Error inflating class fragment
04-04 10:01:35.551: E/AndroidRuntime(14362):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1872)
04-04 10:01:35.551: E/AndroidRuntime(14362):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1893)
04-04 10:01:35.551: E/AndroidRuntime(14362):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-04 10:01:35.551: E/AndroidRuntime(14362):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1054)
04-04 10:01:35.551: E/AndroidRuntime(14362):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-04 10:01:35.551: E/AndroidRuntime(14362):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
04-04 10:01:35.551: E/AndroidRuntime(14362):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4385)
04-04 10:01:35.551: E/AndroidRuntime(14362):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-04 10:01:35.551: E/AndroidRuntime(14362):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-04 10:01:35.551: E/AndroidRuntime(14362):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
04-04 10:01:35.551: E/AndroidRuntime(14362):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
04-04 10:01:35.551: E/AndroidRuntime(14362):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-04 10:01:35.551: E/AndroidRuntime(14362): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29: Error inflating class fragment
04-04 10:01:35.551: E/AndroidRuntime(14362):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:581)
04-04 10:01:35.551: E/AndroidRuntime(14362):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
04-04 10:01:35.551: E/AndroidRuntime(14362):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
04-04 10:01:35.551: E/AndroidRuntime(14362):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
04-04 10:01:35.551: E/AndroidRuntime(14362):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
04-04 10:01:35.551: E/AndroidRuntime(14362):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:250)
04-04 10:01:35.551: E/AndroidRuntime(14362):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1742)
04-04 10:01:35.551: E/AndroidRuntime(14362):    at com.app.thetoolstore.Tool_map.onCreate(Tool_map.java:11)
04-04 10:01:35.551: E/AndroidRuntime(14362):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1072)
04-04 10:01:35.551: E/AndroidRuntime(14362):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1836)
04-04 10:01:35.551: E/AndroidRuntime(14362):    ... 11 more
04-04 10:01:35.551: E/AndroidRuntime(14362): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar:/data/app/com.app.thetoolstore-2.apk]
04-04 10:01:35.551: E/AndroidRuntime(14362):    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
04-04 10:01:35.551: E/AndroidRuntime(14362):    at   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
04-04 10:01:35.551: E/AndroidRuntime(14362):    at  java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
04-04 10:01:35.551: E/AndroidRuntime(14362):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:471)
04-04 10:01:35.551: E/AndroidRuntime(14362):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:549)
04-04 10:01:35.551: E/AndroidRuntime(14362):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
04-04 10:01:35.551: E/AndroidRuntime(14362):    at  android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
04-04 10:01:35.551: E/AndroidRuntime(14362):    ... 20 more
```

**UPDATE**

I solved the issue using this tutorial https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=19nQzvKP-CVLd7_VrpwnHfl-AE9fjbJySowONZZtNHzw speciffically I had issues with the *libs* and google-pay services.

Answer (score 3):

Hmmm lots of issue
1) You need to use FragmentActivity instead of Activity

2) android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" replace by android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

3) You need to add your key in manifest file and use  Google Android Map API v2

4)  Refer this tutorial http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html

Comment: why he need to change this line : com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment  and he already give link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#the_google_maps_api_key have you read question??

Comment: Compatibility and recommended options